# Variable expansion in makefile for loop

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

```
APPS = a b c

a_OBJ = x.o y.o z.o
b_OBJ =  p.o q.o r.o
c_OBJ = s.o t.o k.o

all:
    for i in $(APPS);   \
    do
       echo $("$${i}_OBJ");  \
    done;
```

In the above given sample Makefile I want to print the list of obj files inside the for loop but the list is not getting expanded as expected, what  exactly am I missing here for the proper expansion of the OBJ lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All make does with recipe lines is pass them one by one to the shell after expanding them. Each line is a **seperate** shell instance, so by the time you reach `echo` the shell won't even know about `a b c` let alone the makefile variables `a_OBJ` etc (also it simply fails beforehand because `for i in a b c; do` isn't valid bash syntax - remember each line is completely separate).

You can override this behavior with the `.ONESHELL` special target which will send multiple recipe lines to a single shell instance

```
.ONESHELL:
all:
# etc.
```

but if you try this you'll see that bash executes

```
for i in a b c;   \
do
echo ;  \
done;
```

Make expands `$("$${i}_OBJ")` to an empty string before sending the line to the shell because there's no variable named `"${i}_OBJ"`.

You'll need to expand the variables *before* they are sent with something like the following

```
APPS = a b c

a_OBJ = x.o y.o z.o
b_OBJ =  p.o q.o r.o
c_OBJ = s.o t.o k.o

all: $(APPS)    
$(APPS):
    @echo $($@_OBJ)
```